# Force exerted by pulley on ceiling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, acceleration, weight

I read in my book that when a pulley is accelerating it exerts more force on the ceiling than when it is still. I know the derivation and I can mathematically prove it but I'm unable to get my head around why this happens. Here's a picture that might help:
[image]

Here, the pulley will exert more force when accelerating because the tension is helping it accelerate.
But think from the viewpoint of someone who doesn't know physics at all: just the wheel spinning shouldn't add any extra force if total weight initially and finally are same, right?

Can someone help me correlate the derivation and my logic in simple words?

Comment: What is happening to the center of mass of the system?

Comment: Centre of mass shifts due to external force. Here the centre of mass is shifting downward and the only downward force is gravity. So that causes the object to move. I'm not getting the relation to force exerted on ceiling. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Center of mass shifts due to all external forces.  Gravity and pull from the ceiling are your only external forces.

Comment: The acceleration of masses changes the net force on the pulley, that is $T = m(g-a)$